# Transform sequence in Linq while being aware of each Select/SelectMany result

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my problem. I have one specific list, which I'll present as a `int[]` for simplicity's sake.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Suppose I need to transform each item on this list, but depending on the situation, I may return an int or an array of ints.

As an example, suppose I need to return `{v}` if the value is **odd**, and `{v,v+1}` if the value is **even**. I've done this:

```
int[] b = a.SelectMany(v => v % 2 == 0 ? new int[] { v, v+1 } : new int[] { v })
           .ToArray();
```

So if I run this, I'll get the expected response:

```
{1,2,3,3,4,5,5}
```

See that I have repeating numbers, right? `3` and `5`. I don't want those repeating numbers. Now, you may tell me that I can just call `.Distinct()` after processing the array.

This is the problem. The `SelectMany` clause is fairly complex (I just made up a simpler example), and I definitely don't want to process `3` if it's already present in the list.

I could check if `3` is present in the original list. But if I got `3` in the `SelectMany` clause, I don't want to get it again. For instance, if I had this list:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,2};
```

I would get this:

```
{1,2,3,3,4,5,5,2,3}
```

Thus returning `v` (my original value) and `v+1` again at the end. Just so you can understand it better `v+1` represents some processing I want to avoid.

Summarizing, this is what I want:

1. I have a list of objects. **(Check)**
2. I need to filter them, and depending on the result, I may need to return more than one object. **(Check, used `SelectMany`)**
3. I need them to be distinct, but I can't do that at the end of the process. I should be able to return just `{v}` if `{v+1}` already exists. **(Clueless...)**

One thing I thought about is writing a custom `SelectMany` which may suit my needs, but I want to be sure there's no built-in way to do this.

**EDIT**: I believe I may have mislead you guys with my example. I know how to figure out if `v+1` is in a list. To be clear, I have one object which has 2 int properties, Id and IdParent. I need to "yield return" all the objects **and** their parents. But I just have the ParentId, which comes from the objects themselves. I'm able to know if `v+1` is in the list because I can check if any object there has the same Id as the ParentId I'm checking.

**ANSWER**: I ended up using `Aggregate`, which can be used to do exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does the order of the resulting array matter?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not at all :)

Comment: Just a question, but since linq uses deferred execution, would you be able to run a second linq statement without the first executing?  I don't know if the fist executes when you do the second. aka get rid of the `.ToArray` which executes the commands and then run another linq to filter out the data you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this using `Aggregate` method. You won't be processing numbers that are already in the list, wheather they were in the original list or as a result of applying (v + 1)

```
 int[] v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2 };

 var result = v.Aggregate(new List<int>(),
   (acc, next) =>
   {
     if (!acc.Contains(next))
       return (next % 2 == 0) ? acc.Concat(new int[] { next, next + 1 }).ToList()
                              : acc.Concat(new int[] { next }).ToList();
     else
       return acc;
   }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this simple loop with the `HashSet<int>` help?

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,2};
var aLookupList = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (int i in a)
{
    bool isEven = i % 2 == 0;
    if (isEven)
    {
        aLookupList.Add(i);
        aLookupList.Add(i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        aLookupList.Add(i);
    }
}
var result = aLookupList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var existing = new HashSet<int>(a);

var result = existing
    .Where(v => v % 2 == 0 && !existing.Contains(v + 1))
    .Select(v => v + 1)
    .Concat(existing)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: You are checking the input to see if it is in that list.  I think the OP wanted to make sure it was unique in the output.  In this particular example it would be, but I think this is a simplified version.

Comment: @Harrison Yes, it doesn't need to be necessarily in the original list itself. During the select it may have selected `v+1`, and in this case, I need to be sure it won't select it again.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have this input:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

And the output should also be `{1,2,3,4,5}` because you don't want **duplicated numbers** as you describe.
Because you use an `array` as input, you can try this code:

```
var output = a.SelectMany((x,i)=> x % 2 == 0 ? new []{x,x+1} : 
                                  i > 0 && a[i-1]==x-1 ? new int[]{} : new []{x});
//if the input is {1,2,4,5}
//The output is also {1,2,3,4,5}
```